# JS Promise API: Create a loop of promises and merge result into another object

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I am trying to understand Promise API.

**Test Case:**
I am using three API's, from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

```
/user/{userId} #Returns a user
/posts?userId=1 #Returs list of posts by user
/comments?postId=1 #Returns list of comments for the post
```

I need to combine the output of all three API's into a structure like below.

```
var user = {
    'id' : "1",
    "name" : "Qwerty",
    "posts" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "userid" : 1,
            "message" : "Hello",
            "comments" : [
                {
                    'id' : 1,
                    "postId" :1
                    "userid" : 2,
                    "message" : "Hi!"                   
                },
                {
                    'id' : 2,
                    "postId" :1
                    "userid" : 1,
                    "message" : "Lets meet at 7!"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The challenge I am facing is in merging comments to each post. Please Help. I mean I am not sure what to do.

Current Implementation.

```
var xyz = function (userId) {
    return Promise.all(
        [
            usersApi.getUsersByIdPromise(userId),
            postsApi.getPostsForUserPromise(userId)
        ]
    ).spread((user, posts) => {
        user.posts = posts;

        for (let post of user.posts){
            commentsApi.getCommentsForPostPromise(post.id)
                .then(comments => {                   
                    //Merge comments to post
                    //How do i return a merged user object
                });
        }        
    })
}
```

Comment: What is this `spread` method you've tried to use on the result of `Promise.all`? There is no `spread` in the standard Promise API.

Comment: its http://bluebirdjs.com/, Please give a solution in standard promise API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, see comments:

```
var xyz = function (userId) {
    // Start parallel requests for user and posts
    return Promise.all(
        [
            usersApi.getUsersByIdPromise(userId),
            postsApi.getPostsForUserPromise(userId)
        ]
    ).then(([user, posts]) => { // Note the destructuring
        // We have both user and posts, let's add the posts to the user
        user.posts = posts;

        // Send parallel queries for all the post comments, by
        // using `map` to get an array of promises for each post's
        // comments
        return Promise.all(user.posts.map(post => 
            commentsApi.getCommentsForPostPromise(post.id)
                .then(comments => {                   
                    // Have the comments for this post, remember them
                    post.comments = comments;
                })
            ))
            // When all of those comments requests are done, set the
            // user as the final resolution value in the chain
            .then(_ => user);
    });
};
```

Example:

```js
// Mocks
var commentId = 0;
var usersApi = {
    getUsersByIdPromise(userId) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ => resolve({id: userId, name: "Some User"}), 100);
        });
    }
};
var postsApi = {
    getPostsForUserPromise(userId) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ => resolve([
                {userId: userId, id: 1, title: "Post 1"},
                {userId: userId, id: 2, title: "Post 2"}
            ]), 100);
        });
    }
};
var commentsApi = {
    getCommentsForPostPromise(postId) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ => resolve([
                {postId: postId, id: ++commentId, title: "First comment on post id = " + postId},
                {postId: postId, id: ++commentId, title: "Second comment on post id = " + postId},
                {postId: postId, id: ++commentId, title: "Third comment on post id = " + postId}
            ]), 100);
        });
    }
};
// Code
var xyz = function (userId) {
    // Start parallel requests for user and posts
    return Promise.all(
        [
            usersApi.getUsersByIdPromise(userId),
            postsApi.getPostsForUserPromise(userId)
        ]
    ).then(([user, posts]) => { // Note the destructuring
        // We have both user and posts, let's add the posts to the user
        user.posts = posts;

        // Send parallel queries for all the post comments, by
        // using `map` to get an array of promises for each post's
        // comments
        return Promise.all(user.posts.map(post => 
            commentsApi.getCommentsForPostPromise(post.id)
                .then(comments => {                   
                    // Have the comments for this post, remember them
                    post.comments = comments;
                })
            ))
            // When all of those comments requests are done, set the
            // user as the final resolution value in the chain
            .then(_ => user);
    });
};
// Using it
xyz().then(user => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Although actually, we could start requesting the comments for the posts as soon as we have the posts, without waiting for the user until later:

```
var xyz = function (userId) {
    return Promise.all(
        [
            usersApi.getUsersByIdPromise(userId),
            postsApi.getPostsForUserPromise(userId).then(posts =>
                // We have the posts, start parallel requests for their comments
                Promise.all(posts.map(post => 
                    commentsApi.getCommentsForPostPromise(post.id)
                        .then(comments => {
                            // Have the post's comments, remember them
                            post.comments = comments;
                        })
                ))
                // We have all the comments, resolve with posts
                .then(_ => posts)
            )
        ]
    ).then(([user, posts]) => { // Note the destructuring
        // We have both user and posts (with their filled-in comments)
        // Remember the posts on the user, and return the user as the final
        // resolution value in the chain
        user.posts = posts;
        return user;
    });
};
```

Example:

```js
// Mocks
var commentId = 0;
var usersApi = {
    getUsersByIdPromise(userId) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ => resolve({id: userId, name: "Some User"}), 100);
        });
    }
};
var postsApi = {
    getPostsForUserPromise(userId) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ => resolve([
                {userId: userId, id: 1, title: "Post 1"},
                {userId: userId, id: 2, title: "Post 2"}
            ]), 100);
        });
    }
};
var commentsApi = {
    getCommentsForPostPromise(postId) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ => resolve([
                {postId: postId, id: ++commentId, title: "First comment on post id = " + postId},
                {postId: postId, id: ++commentId, title: "Second comment on post id = " + postId},
                {postId: postId, id: ++commentId, title: "Third comment on post id = " + postId}
            ]), 100);
        });
    }
};
// Code
var xyz = function (userId) {
    return Promise.all(
        [
            usersApi.getUsersByIdPromise(userId),
            postsApi.getPostsForUserPromise(userId).then(posts =>
                // We have the posts, start parallel requests for their comments
                Promise.all(posts.map(post => 
                    commentsApi.getCommentsForPostPromise(post.id)
                        .then(comments => {
                            // Have the post's comments, remember them
                            post.comments = comments;
                        })
                ))
                // We have all the comments, resolve with posts
                .then(_ => posts)
            )
        ]
    ).then(([user, posts]) => { // Note the destructuring
        // We have both user and posts (with their filled-in comments)
        // Remember the posts on the user, and return the user as the final
        // resolution value in the chain
        user.posts = posts;
        return user;
    });
};
// Using it
xyz().then(user => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: You should change the `post.comments = post` to `post.comments = comments`

Comment: @nicowernli: LOL, yes, yes, I should, thanks. :-) *(Edit: Fixed)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, both not working for me, I am running as node application. no errors as well. `.then(_ => { console.log(posts);resolve(posts)})` nothing is printed here. Could be something wrong with the environment. Also, I had to change `[user, posts]` to `(user, posts)`

Comment: @titogeo: I had a minor syntax error (you need `()` around the destructuring parameters) and a small nesting error in the second example. Shouldn't be anything environment-specific here. I've fixed those minor errors above and added live examples.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks you so much, both works now. You see any advantages over v1 vs v2 or vice versa. For me, v2 was a tad difficult to understand.

Comment: @titogeo: v2 allows for more overlap and so could complete faster: If the query for the post completes before the query for the user, it doesn't wait until the user query completes before requesting the comments. v1 waits until both post and user are in, and only then asks for comments.